# Python library to determine the input device (keyboard) used

Tags: linux, python, keyboard, debian, input-devices

I have a problem about determining the keyboards. Let me explain what I want.

I have a Linux Single Board Computer which has two connected keyboards(readers). Let's say one of them is keyboard_one and the other one is keyboard_two. I wrote a program which takes input from user ( it is worked as a keypad - takes password). I can take the passwords and check it is granted or denied well but:

I need to determine which password is come from keyboard_one or which one is come from keyboard_two.

So I'm looking for a python library/module that can accomplish this. In case it matters, I am using Debian and coding with Python.

Comment: Welcome. Your question is off topic, as it does not ask us to recommend software. Please read [ask] Keyboards, mice, etc are all lumped under Human Interface  Devices (HID), so google around with that phrase. And, good luck

Comment: A welcome from me as well! You'd brought me into a conflict, Felix: I didn't want to contradict @MawgsaysreinstateMonica – but I thought a little rephrasing might help your issue. Did I understand your needs correctly? In that case I hope Mawg will forgive me, we can simply cleanup comments, and wish for some good recommendations to arrive soon. (Mawg: there's certainly a Python lib telling `dev/ttyX` from `/dev/ttyZ`, so would you agree with my rephrasing? I wouldn't even wonder much if that lib already ships inside `os.*` ;)

Comment: Lolx!! I would like it think that there is always a welcome for new participants :-)  It seems like a few comments were deleted, but  the update to say "`I'm looking for a python library/module`" certainly makes this question on-topic.  OP, please don't think that we  think that new-guy questions are always knee-jerk & that we are anti new guys or even unclear questions. It's just a matter of "please give us info to help us to help you". Again - welcome aboard - we want to help you (ad hope that maybe you can help others)  (p.s thanx @Izzy ;-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica no deleted comments. If you check the post history, I simply deduced that from the concluding sentence. I might be wrong with it (needs Felix to say – I hope we didn't scare him away with our word play) – but even if, I'd say answers to this rephrased question will help him. And that's what it's about, right? ;)

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what it is about. That and nothing else. IIRC, you can't tell on Windows - it's all just input from the HDMI. On Linux, I would expect to be able to read from `/devusb0`, `/dev/usb1`, etc, but I can't say for sure. Although my profession is developing for Linux targets, it's all embedded - and we don't any HID.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I DuckDuckGoed that for you. See the accepted answer to [How to distinguish input from different keyboards?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72483/how-to-distinguish-input-from-different-keyboards). No library required, apparently.

> If you're using Linux, the best way to distinguish between input
> devices is to use the Linux Event Interface. After a device's
> hardware-specific input is decoded, it's converted to an intermediate
> Linux-specific event structure and made available by reading one or
> more of the character devices under /dev/input/. This is completely
> independent of the programming language you use, by the way.
>
> Each hardware device gets its own /dev/input/eventX device, and there
> are also aggregates (e.g. /dev/input/mice which represents the motion
> of all mice in the system). Your system may also have
> /dev/input/by-path and /dev/input/by-id.
>
> There's an ioctl called EVIOCGNAME which returns the name of the
> device as a humanly-readable string, or you can use something like
> /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Gaming_Mouse-mouse.
>
> You open the device, and every time an event arrives from the input
> hardware, you'll get a packet of data. If you can read C, you can
> study the file /usr/include/linux/input.h which shows exactly how this
> stuff works. If you don't, you could read this question which provides
> all the information you need.
>
> The good thing about the event interface is that you just find out
> what device you need, and you can read input from that input device
> only, ignoring all others. You'll also get notifications about keys,
> buttons and controls you normally wouldn't by just reading the
> ‘cooked’ character stream from a terminal: even dead keys like Shift,
> etc.
>
> The bad thing is that the event interface doesn't return ‘cooked’
> characters, it just uses numeric codes for keys (the codes
> corresponding to each key are found in the aforementioned header file
> — but also in the Python source of event.py. If your input device has
> unusual keys/buttons, you may need to experiment a bit till you get
> the right numbers.

Thanks, @Alexios, for the answer